# U-boot: how to check if tftp command successfully loaded image into ram?

Tags: u-boot

I load a rootfs image into RAM via u-boot tftp and flash it to the device flash storage. This is currently done manually, but now I want to do it automatically via a u-boot script:

```
tftp ${rootfs_image};
mmc write ${loadaddr} ${blk} ${cnt}
```

However, when it looks for an image from the tftp server with the u-boot `tftp ${rootfs_image}` command and it *DOESN'T* find the image, I don't want to run the `mmc write` part of the script.

How do I check if the tftp command successfully downloaded the image into RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the TFTP protocol does not ensure that the integrity of the transferred data will be preserved - see section *Security Consideration* in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol).

Assuming your u-boot has the `hash` command available, or that you can re-compile it with `CONFIG_CMD_HASH=y`, you could use an [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hash for verifying that your image was properly transferred:

On a Linux TFTP server:

```
# create an image for the purpose of the example
echo "Binary Image" > image.bin

# display sha256 hash for image.bin
sha256sum -b image.bin
36949f85f1bff0d5d1dd5fcfdfd725e919b0ee64be24f7f3ccfb53908fd09550 *image.bin

# create a file containing the hash in binary
# credits:
sha256sum -b image.bin | xxd -r -p > image.bin.sha256sum.bin

# display content of binary file
hexdump -C image.bin.sha256sum.bin
00000000  36 94 9f 85 f1 bf f0 d5  d1 dd 5f cf df d7 25 e9  |6........._...%.|
00000010  19 b0 ee 64 be 24 f7 f3  cc fb 53 90 8f d0 95 50  |...d.$....S....P|
00000020
```

On your u-boot system (using the memory layout available on my Alwinner H5 system here):

```
# 0x40080000: address where image.bin will be transfered
# 0x40090000: address where image.bin.sha256sum.bin will be transfrered
# 0x40090000: address where the sha256 has will be computed by u-boot on the 13 bytes of image.bin

# clearing memory
mw.b 0x40080000 0 0x2000
mw.b 0x40090000 0 0x20
mw.b 0x400A0000 0 0x20

md.b 0x40080000 0x20
40080000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
40080010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

md.b 0x40090000 0x20
40090000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
40090010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

md.b 0x400A0000 0x20
400a0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
400a0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

tftp 0x40080000 image.bin
Using ethernet@1c30000 device
TFTP from server 192.168.1.22; our IP address is 192.168.1.2
Filename 'image.bin'.
Load address: 0x40080000
Loading: #
     5.9 KiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 13 (d hex)

tftp 0x40090000 image.bin.sha256sum.bin
Using ethernet@1c30000 device
TFTP from server 192.168.1.22; our IP address is 192.168.1.2
Filename 'image.bin.sha256sum.bin'.
Load address: 0x40090000
Loading: #
     15.6 KiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 32 (20 hex)

 md.b 0x40090000 0x20
40090000: 36 94 9f 85 f1 bf f0 d5 d1 dd 5f cf df d7 25 e9    6........._...%.
40090010: 19 b0 ee 64 be 24 f7 f3 cc fb 53 90 8f d0 95 50    ...d.$....S....P

hash sha256  0x40080000 0x0d *0x400A0000
sha256 for 40080000 ... 4008000c ==> 36949f85f1bff0d5d1dd5fcfdfd725e919b0ee64be24f7f3ccfb53908fd09550

cmp.b 0x40090000 0x400A0000 0x20
Total of 32 byte(s) were the same

echo $?
0
```

In the case image.bin and/or image.bin.sha256sum.bin would have been improperly transferred, the chances that the computed sha256 would match the transferred one are extremely unlikely - using SHA-512 would make this even more unlikely. 
The outcome would have been in the case of an incorrect transfer:

```
echo $?
1
```

In real life, this would be more practical to transfer an image with a fixed, maximum length, for example padded with zeroes, so that a u-boot script responsible for validating the transferred image would use a fixed length, say 8 KiB, that is 0x2000 bytes.

```
ls -lgG image.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 13 Dec 17 20:34 image.bin

dd if=/dev/zero  of=image.bin  bs=8K count=1  oflag=append
ls -lgG image.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 8192 Dec 17 21:03 image.bin
hexdump -C image.bin
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002000

The correct u-boot command to use for computing the hash would be:
hash sha256  0x40080000 0x2000 *0x400A0000
```

And a new binary file containing the new hash would of course have to be created as well:

```
sha256sum -b image.bin | xxd -r -p > image.bin.sha256sum.bin
```

I used two files for the purpose of the example, but you could just append `image.bin.sha256sum.bin` to `image.bin` and transfer one single file.

You would have to replace `0x400A0000` by `0x40082000` in the `hash` and `cmp` commands.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Very thorough answer! I didn't think much of the integrity of the downloaded image, but of course it makes sense to check it (especially as i will use this as a recovery flashing) so i will definitely try to implement this. Thanks.

Comment: I appear to have a problem getting the hash function into u-boot. I am using u-boot-tegra for my nvidia jetson nano, and putting in `CONFIG_CMD_HASH=y` was not enough. Right now I'm attempting to add `#define CONFIG_CMD_HASH`, `#define CONFIG_SHA256` and `#define CONFIG_SHA_HW_ACCEL` into my machine configuration but i'm getting errors when building. Do you happen to know what lines are needed and where to put them in the u-boot files?

Comment: Adding `CONFIG_CMD_HASH=y` to  `orangepi_pc2_defconfig` is sufficient in `u-boot 2019.09`. Where could I download `u-boot-tegra` from, and what is the config file you are using ? What are the error messages you are getting ?

Comment: I managed to get hash function into u-boot, i just had to remove `#define CONFIG_SHA_HW_ACCEL` from `u-boot-tegra/include/configs/p3450-porg.h`, so i guess the hasing algorithm isn't hardware accelerated in my case. If you still wanna take a look, u-boot-tegra is from [here](https://github.com/madisongh/u-boot-tegra). I use it in Yocto through the [meta-tegra layer](https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra) as part of the bsp.

Answer (score 1):

The tftp command returns true if it succeeds. So you could write:

```
tftp ${rootfs_image} && mmc write ${loadaddr} ${blk} ${cnt}
```

Now *mmc write* will only be executed if the *tftp* command succeeds.

Comment: Short and dirty version of @Frant's answer without the security. I will use this until i get the added integrity check to work from his answer. Thanks!